# Laravel eloquent if 'anonym' field is 1, change 'username' to anonym

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a `Posts` table which contains a column `anonym` that can be either 1 or 0. I select the posts using Eloquent and join the user like this:

```
$posts = Post::with(
    array('user'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','username');
    }))
    ->with('category')
    ->withCount('likes')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(25);
```

The return looks like this:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 116,
        "user_id": 3,
        ...
        "anonym": 1,
        "likes_count": 0,
        "user": {
            "id": 3,
            "username": "Max"
        },
        "category": null,
    },
```

Now, when the value of `anonym` in the posts table is `1`, I want the username not to be e.g. 'Max' but 'Anonym'. I tried it with a raw query, but I'm unable to get it to work.

Is this even possible with eloquent?

EDIT:

I tried the following as suggested:

```
array('user'=>function($query){
    $query->select(DB::raw("IF(`posts`.`anonym` = 0, `users`.`username`, 'Anonym') as username"));
}))
```

but I get the error, that posts.anonym cannot be found:

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts.anonym' in 'field list' (SQL: select IF(`posts`.`anonym` = 0, `users`.`username`, 'Anonym') as username from `users` where `users`.`id` in (1))

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$posts = Post::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
->select(
  'posts.*', 
  DB::raw('IF(`posts`.`anonym`, `users`.`username`, "Anonym") as username')
)
->with('category')
->withCount('likes')
->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
->paginate(25);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I get the error that posts.anonym cannot be found: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts.anonym' in 'field list' (SQL: select IF(`posts`.`anonym` = 0, `users`.`username`, 'Anonym') as username from `users` where `users`.`id` in (1))

Comment: Yes the issue seems to occur because when `with` is called, it creates a second query instead of working in tandem with the first one. Another option would be to do a full query with a `join` with `users`, though with that method you'd have it all as part of the same object. If you don't mind, I'll update my answer for that version of the workaround.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much. Had to switch the IF arguments `DB::raw('IF(posts.anonym, "Anonym", users.username) as username')` and now it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting messy with queries, it might be easier to take advantage of Eloquent's [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) and [Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) in your `Post` model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'anonym' => 'boolean',
];

public function getAuthorAttribute()
{
    return $this->anonym ? 'Anonym' : $this->user->username;
}
```

First, it casts `anonym` as a bool so you don't need to worry whether it's really an integer or string.

When you `echo $post->author`, Eloquent will silently call `getAuthorAttribute()` in the background. Since `author` doesn't really exist as an attribute, you can name it just about anything.